# How come java.lang.String does not validate encoding?

Tags: java, utf-8, decoding

I ran in to something that surprised me a little. When trying to build a string from bytes that are not proper utf-8, the String constructor still gives me a result. No exception is thrown. Example:

```
byte[] x = { (byte) 0xf0, (byte) 0xab };
new String(x, "UTF-8"); // This works, or at least gives a result

// This however, throws java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 3
ByteBuffer wrapped = ByteBuffer.wrap(x);
CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
decoder.decode(wrapped);
```

Trying the same thing in for example python also gives an error, with a somewhat clearer error message:

```
   >>> '\xf0\xab'.decode('utf-8')
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
       return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: unexpected end of data
```

So why is it that the java string constructor seems to ignore errors in the input?

update: I should be a little more clear. The javadoc points out that this is unspecified. But what could the reason be for implementing it like this? It seems to me you would never want this sort of behavior and any time you can't be 100% sure of the source you would need to use the CharsetDecoder to be safe.

Comment: Javadoc: _"This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement string. The CharsetDecoder class should be used when more control over the decoding process is required"_ -- is that not clear?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is. Still not clear to me _why_ that is the implementation. Like... when is this a useful behavior? It seems to me that this is just not doing what I expect and not telling me about it.

Answer (score 1):

The Java documentation for [String(byte[], String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-java.lang.String-) says:

> **The behavior** of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in
>   the given charset **is unspecified**. The CharsetDecoder class should be
>   used when more control over the decoding process is required.

Thee constructor [String(byte[], Charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-java.nio.charset.Charset-) has yet another behavior:

> This method always **replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character
>   sequences with this charset's default replacement string**. The
>   CharsetDecoder class should be used when more control over the
>   decoding process is required.

I like Phython's behavior better. But you can't expect Java to be exactly like Python.

Comment: I didn't actually notice the difference between String(byte[], String) and String(byte[], Charset) before. That makes it even stranger, I think. :)